# Next power of 2 for a number (in search for better "bit-twiddling" way)

Tags: c, optimization, low-level, bitwise-operators, arithmetic

I just wonder if there exists *better* (i.e. faster?) way to get the next
power of 2 for a given number than the following one (maybe some
*better* sort of "bit-twiddling" hack is possible?) ...

```
static size_t
npow2(size_t n)
{
        n--;
        n |= n >> 1;
        n |= n >> 2;
        n |= n >> 4;
        n |= n >> 8;
        n |= n >> 16;
        return n + 1;
}
```

Thanks for your ideas.

Comment: **Unclear what help you need.** Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell what problem you are trying to solve or what aspect of your approach needs to be corrected or explained. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I think this question would be better suited for SO, since it is about specific implementation details in C.

Comment: @gnat: The question is pretty clear and unambiguous, I think.

Comment: @DocBrown: The mathematics of bit manipulation should make this question algorithmic enough to be suited for here; particularly if you go by the _"SO for when you're in front of a compiler/editor, Programmers for when you're in front of a whiteboard"_ test.

Comment: It's worth noting that the given `npow2` function won't work on a system where `size_t` is larger than 32-bits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Sean Eron Anderson's collection of [Bit Twiddling Hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#RoundUpPowerOf2Float), that's probably the fastest way.

The alternatives are an IEEE float casting hack, which involves fewer C operations but ends up slower, and directly using the x86 BSR (bit scan reverse) machine instruction, but in Anderson's testing that didn't end up significantly faster than the above OR-ing trick.